# How to find and click link based on the letters/words it contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, click, getelementsbyclassname

I have this code that was working up until recently, not sure why, but I think it's because there are 2 links with the same class name.

This is how the code originally looked --

```
if (tweet[0].match(theName) == theName) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[0].click();
        tFunction = "get outa here";
        theName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to jump out of interval loop

    }
```

This is how my code looks now, its part of a function that scans and refresh until variables are matched so that I can then click the link --

```
if (tweet[0].match(theName) == theName) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link").find("a:contains('swoo.sh')").bind('click', function() {
            window.location.href = this.href;
            return false;
        }).trigger('click');
        tFunction = "get outa here";
        theName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to jump out of interval loop

    }
```

The problem is theres usually 2 links, and the wrong link ends up getting clicked, so Im looking for a way to match some of the text from the link (ie. swoo ) that I want it to click.

I was trying to use another code, but it required I inject jquery library  (because of $) which I cant do/dont want to do cause its a chrome extension.

Any idea on how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Your second code-block uses jQuery anyway (in case you didn't notice).</sub>

Regarding your first code-block (and putting aside the fact that I have no idea what those `tFunction` and `theName` are for), you can modify it like this:

```
if (tweet[0].match(theName) == theName) {
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a.twitter-timeline-link'))
      .some(function(elem) {
        if (elem.textContent.indexOf('swoo.sh') > -1) {
            elem.click();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    tFunction = ...;
    theName = ...;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Using the sample extension below, I was able to get my link clicked :)
It reloads the page every second, until it finds the specified shoe-entry, then it looks for the correct link (containing 'swoo.sh') and clicks it.

**UPDATE 2:**

It turned out some dynamic DOM manipulation was causing inconsistent behaviour when there was a lag in the network-connection. I made some modifications in the code to take into account the element's attributes (which are unaffected by dynamic DOM element creation and offer increased consistency). In fact, I was not able to reproduce any sort of inconsistency after trying a dozen of times (which was **not** the case with the previous approach).

**content.js:**

```
var shoeName = ...;
var tweets = new Array();

function twitterScan() {

    tweets = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text"));

    var targetLink = null;
    var foundTweet = tweets.some(function(tweet) {
        if (tweet.innerHTML.indexOf(shoeName) !== -1) {
            var foundLink = [].slice
                    .call(tweet.querySelectorAll('a.twitter-timeline-link'))
                    .some(function(el) {
                if (el.dataset.expandedUrl.indexOf('swoo.sh') !== -1) {
                    targetLink = el;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
            if (!foundLink) {
                alert('Found ' + shoeName + ', but couldn\'t find the link :(');
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    if (targetLink) {
        window.open(targetLink.href);
    } else if (!foundTweet) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}

setTimeout(twitterScan, 1000);
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": false,

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://some.domain.com/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }]
}
```

Comment: yeah I know it use jquery but when I try to use '$' or 'jQuery' I run into the problem of having to embed the jquery library with my extension. I tried using the code and receive this error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: You tried my code and received error ? At what line/column ? Did you replace the `...` with the actual values ?

Comment: Yea I replaced the ... with the values. And it doesnt tell me in the console what line.

Comment: do you have a email I can contact you at? This way I can show you my full code and what Im trying to do?

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. It worked fine for me. Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helps you solve your problem.

Comment: I had to add var tFunction = "twitterScan()"; for it to even do anything, but even then its still clicking the "pic...." like instead of the "swoo" link

Comment: The alert pops up when the swoo link is not present though

Comment: 1. I forgot to update the timeout callback (it is fixed now - no need for `tFunction`). 2. It was definitely clicking the `swoo.sh` link when I tried it. 3. If you don't want the alert feel free to edit the code and remove that check. BTW, please accept/upvote the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Ok I think I got it to work, it seems that it only works sometimes. It'll just flash, or itll click the picture link, it seems to never be 100% clicking the correct link. Im going to do some more test in a few and Ill accept your answer. Can you edit your answer to match the variables in my question ie. 'theName'.

Comment: Yeah thats a major problem, and basically leaves me right where I was when I posted this question - It works when it wants to and clicks the wrong link sometimes or just flashes quickly and doesnt continue trying. Im trying to get precise 100% of the time thats why I thought by searching for certain text in the link, it will be accurate all the time... =(

Comment: It works for me all the time. MAybe you can provide some more info (e.g. on what input does it fail) so I can help with debuggin, since you cannot fix it yourself.

Comment: Lol, it is kind of not-so-nice to say you are just were you started, aftetr all the work that is done for you !

Comment: lol sorry, it's just that Im experiencing the same problems. Im not sure what input it fails. If you go to the test page and try refreshing a bunch of times, you'll see that sometimes I clicks the right link (thats when the new page opens up) but most of the time it will just click the picture link (thats when the pop up with the picture shows up) while other times it just flashes the pop up with image real quick but does nothing after. Im not sure how to debug cause I cant pin point the issue.

Comment: I think it has to do something with the cache, if I hold down the reload button and select empty cache and hard reload it works, but if I keep doing it, after a while it will just click the tweet/image and not the correct link

Comment: @user3089477: It might be a little late now, but I updated the code (again) to fix the issue you mentioned. Maybe next time you can put your extension in good use ;) If you think this answer adequately addresses your problem, please consider accepting/upvoting.

Comment: !!!!! lol thanks. I just have a couple of questions about the code, I'll email you.

Comment: Amazing work @ExpertSystem! I'm looking at this a year ago, and works like a charm. Only with a few changes according to the new 2015 Twitter.